# Get parent from a collection that's already in a collection

Tags: python, scripting, collections

Im really struggling with what seems to be an easy task, however Im not able to make this work.

I need to get the parent inside of a collection that's already in a collection,

with the code im using

```
    print(collection)
    if collection.name == doorname:
        door = collection.children[0]
        print(door) //OUTPUT: <bpy_struct, Collection("Door") at 0x7ff8f180b678>
        for objects in door:
            print(objects) //Error
```

I want all the objects in the Door collection to be printed.
Is there a way to do this, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suggest this is `for o in door.objects` or `for o in door.all_objects` to get all objects in door collection and its children.

Comment: See also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145620/looping-over-hierarchies-of-objects-with-python  .. Can you clarify, comment above addresses error in code, whereas https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146685/how-to-obtain-the-parent-of-a-collection-using-python  would appear to answer the question title.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `for objects in door.children` since you're parenting them?

[image]

Yeah it could be cool to use magic method looping over children